# Below code is working in Angular 8. But I need to execute it in Angular 6. How can i achieve this?

Tags: angular

This code is working in Angular 8 as expected:

```
declare var GlgToolkit: any;

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-glg-dashboard',
    templateUrl: './glg-dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./glg-dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class GlgDashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    glg = new GlgToolkit();

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

When I use same code in angular 6 then gives error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: GlgToolkit is not
>   defined ReferenceError: GlgToolkit is not defined
>       at new GlgDashboardComponent (glg-dashboard.component.ts:16)
>       at createClass (core.js:9084)
>       at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:8971)
>       at createViewNodes (core.js:10191)
>       at createRootView (core.js:10105)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11136)
>       at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:10623)
>       at ComponentFactory_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactory_.create
>   (core.js:8451)
>       at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create
>   (core.js:3265)
>       at ViewContainerRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewContainerRef_.createComponent (core.js:8561)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
>       at zone.js:873
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:421)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3751)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:420)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)

Comment: you need find compatible version of GlgToolkit for Angular 6

Comment: I have the all libraries which supports GLG..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have solved this problem by adding below line in index.html.

```
  <script defer src="assets/Js/GlgToolkitCE.js"></script>
```

> And it's working for me.